# RSA Archer data feed uses plaintext password

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

RSA Archer, version 6.4 SP1 P2.

I use Database Query Transporter for Oracle DB. I configured ODBC Data Provider with a connection string:

```
Driver={Oracle in instantclient_19_3};Dbq=my_id;Uis=my_username;Pwd=my_password;
```

It works, but I hate to have my password in plaintext. Especially that below Connection String, there are dedicated fields for *User Name* and *Password*. But for some reason Archer doesn't use it. How can I force Archer to use data from those fields?

I don't use Instant Client, because I don't have rights to install package the Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Redistributable on the web server.

I'm open to any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diodak, fill out the username and password fields and in the connection string use the following:

```
Driver={Oracle in instantclient_19_3};Dbq=my_id;Uis={username};Pwd={password};
```

Archer will insert the values from the those fields into the connection string when the connection is made to the database server.